# Create Word Document from PHP Documentation

Tags: php, ms-word, doxygen, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

To document my code I thought it would be best practice to use phpDoc syntax, because there are several parsers out there and some IDEs create IntelliSense out of it.

Now I need to put the documentation (API) into a word file, but I don't know which parser is able to output .doc or similar.

I tried DoxyGen, which outputs .rtf and phpDocumentor2, which can only export to .html and .xml (?).

Is there a way to generate a .doc(x) file from phpDoc? Or a simple way to get a document which can be imported to word?
I would appreciate if I don't have to change the phpDoc syntax, because my documentation is very long.

---

Edit: The prefered parser would be phpDocumentor2, because it supports PHP 5.3 functionalities and it's faster than DoxyGen, but phpDocumentor2 has less features than phpDocumentor, which is no longer maintained, related to output formats.

---

Edit: I tried to copy content from the .rtf file into the .docx file, but when I select 'Use Destination Styles', both Word instances suspend and do not respond.

Comment: .rtf can be opened in Word.

Comment: You could try parsing the phpDoc tags and using [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to write the .docx file

Comment: @Jessica I didn't mention that this would work, but I cannot edit the format. I already have a word file with many styles for headings. So I would have to redefine all the headings in the RTF-File.

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't want to create a PHP document in my code. The comments in my code should be processed to a word file.

Comment: What do you suppose PHPWord actually does? It doesn't create PHP documents, it creates OfficeOpenXML MS Word documents!

Comment: I dont't want to create a Word document IN my code, but my COMMENTS in my code should be processed to a word file.
Do you mean I should write my own parser and read my PHP files to generate a Word file? Sorry, had a typo in my comment. (PHP document -> word document)

Comment: @Pixelmonster I think you will be hard pressed to find a source code document generator which supports native output to word.

Comment: @BinaryAlchemist I wouldn't ask if I wouldn't have searched for the last 5 hours.^^ Is there a simple way to export latex to word or somthing like this?

Comment: @Jessica please see my second edit

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you want one large Word doc that contains all the info for your project in the one doc/file... therefore just opening the phpDoc2 HTML output into Word in order to convert it to docx will not meet your need, since that would be one docx per phpdoc2 HTML page.

You might try altering your searches to be for a tool that can spider a given HTML page, recursively pick up all its target page hierarchy, and convert it all into a single docx.  You might have more luck finding a tool that does this but produces a PDF... then you could just use Word to convert the PDF into docx.